# Print the values in group of two in reactjs using .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

I am trying to render a `<li>` which will print two `to` values in a single line. And then the third to value in the next `<li>`.
So my object is like this.

```
let obj = [ 
{from : 'a1' , to : 'a7'},
{from : 'b1' , to : 'b7',
{from : 'c4' , to : 'c27'},
{from : 'a1' , to : 'a9'},
{from : 'j1' , to : 'a10'}
]
```

I want to output it like

```
1. a7 , b7
2. c27, a9
3.  a10
```

`The obj` is a react state. I am printing it using .map() function in js. But I want it to print in pairs of two. How can I achieve that.

```
moves.map((move, i) => {
                            return (
                                <li key={i}>{i}
                                    {move}
                                </li>
                            )
                        })
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to iterate your `obj` variable pariwise.

```
const moves = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i += 2) {
    let move = obj[i].to;
    if (i + 1 < obj.length) {
      move += ", " + obj[i + 1].to;
    }
    moves.push(move);
  }
```

Then, you can simply iterate the newly created `moves` variable.

```
{moves.map((move, i) => {
        return (
          <p key={i}>
            {i + 1}. {move}
          </p>
        );
      })}
```

**Note:** You can use `li` instead of `p` tag.

**Result:**

[image]

**Working demo** at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-pascal-czl09?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like:

```
moves.map((move, i) => {
    return (
        <li key={i}>{i}
            {`move[i].to` + move[i+1] ? `, move[i+1].to` :''}
        </li>
    )
})
```